# How to control what happens when I tab or enter or return in a cell?

Tags: macos, numbers

I'm adding data to a sheet on macOS. There are exactly 4 columns. Ideally when I'm done with a line and hit tab or return, it'd go the the next row at the start of the line. It seems like I've had it do every possible thing: Go the second column on the next line, go directly down one, just stay there, create a new column...

Is there someplace I can tell it what to do? The inconsistency is maddening.